# Android: override onDraw without subclassing when View has been instantiated from xml

Tags: android, ondraw, anonymous-inner-class

I have a class ConditionalEditText which is a compound custom view containing an EditText and a TextView. The layout of this view is defined in XML. I want to override the onDraw method of the EditText. But since it has been instantiated from XML. I cannot do something like

```
EditText edt = new EditText() {
    protected void onDraw() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Is there any way to override the onDraw() method other than sublclassing EditText or doing the UI instantiation is Java rather than XML?

Answer (score 0):

You should override EditText and then instantiate your own custom EditText in xml :

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void onDraw() {
        // your code
    }
}
```

For xml instantiation :

```
<com.android.example.CustomEditText
    ...
/>
```

For more information, see the official documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying

Comment: I know I can always do that. What I want to know is whether I could override the method using an anonymous inner class, like I mentioned in the question.

Comment: sorry, i had not seen the last part. I do not think it is possible without extending the class